In the TV drama "Based on a true story", how can the serial killer collect money from his podcast anonymously?
In the TV drama "Based on a True Story," the serial killer podcast generated significant revenue. The killer managed to collect money without revealing his real identity. There will always be electronic money traces left behind on an online platform. Spotify was mentioned in one of the episodes. How can that be possible?
Is this a major loophole in the plot?

Paid to a solicitor? Paid in bitcoin?
